# 'Settings' object has no attribute Django Restframework

Tags: python, django

I know this question has been asked before. But I am unable to understand the answer.
I have defined an environment variable in *settings.py*

```
s3path=env('S3PATH')
```

Then I call it in *views.py*

```
from django.conf import settings as conf_settings
conf_settings.s3path
```

but I am getting this error

> 'Settings' object has no attribute 's3path'

Answer (score 2):

Settings must be uppercase or they will not be available on the settings object [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings)

Change the setting to be uppercase

```
S3PATH = env('S3PATH')
```

The setting will now be available

```
from django.conf import settings as conf_settings
conf_settings.S3PATH
```

Comment: yes, its upper case issue